# Images repeating themselves in Firebase Database query

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

In my `CardStackFragment.java` I have a query that retrieves 5 random images from my Firebase Realtime Database.
This is the code I use to retrieve them:

```
final DatabaseReference countriesRef = mDatabase.child("paises");
    final ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            countriesRef.removeEventListener(this);
            List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> nomePaisList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                String url = ds.child("Imagem").getValue(String.class); 
                String nomePais = ds.child("Nome").getValue(String.class); 
                urlList.add(url); // Adiciona as imagens à lista
                nomePaisList.add(nomePais); // Adiciona os nomes à lista
            }

            int urlCount = urlList.size();

            int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(urlCount);

            final List<String> randomUrlList = new ArrayList<>(); 
            final List<String> randomNomePaisList = new ArrayList<>(); 


            for (int i=0; i<=Constants.TOTAL_PAISES; i++)
            {
                randomUrlList.add(urlList.get(randomNumber)); 
                randomNomePaisList.add(nomePaisList.get(randomNumber)); 

                    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(randomUrlList.get(i)).into(imgFotoPais); 
                txtPaisNome.setText(randomNomePaisList.get(i)); 
                final int temp_i = i;
 imgFotoPais.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
                        editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("FotoPaisCardParaInfo", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putString("fotoPaisCard", randomUrlList.get(temp_i));
                        editor.putString("nomePaisCard",randomNomePaisList.get(temp_i));
                        editor.commit();


                        Intent intentIntro = new Intent(getActivity(), CountryInfoActivity.class); // Cria o intent "intentIntro"
                        startActivity(intentIntro); // Inicia a atividade IntroActivity
                        getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up_info, R.anim.nothing);
                    }
                });
```

It works fine. Every time I reload it shows my different random images, the problem is that those images can repeat themselves.
For example, if I have 10 images, it could display:
**1, 3, 7, 1, 9**
How can I assure that the images do not repeat themselves?

**UPDATE**
Since nobody answered me and I made this question a few hours from now I will try to exemplify what is happening through a simple gif:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

As you can see, Portugal is showing two times... This can happen with every country... Can someone help me?

**UPDATE**
These are the lines from 90-100

```
  if(!randomUrlList.contains(urlList.get(randomNumber))) {
                    randomUrlList.add(urlList.get(randomNumber)); // Guarda um valor ao calhas de um país
                    randomNomePaisList.add(nomePaisList.get(randomNumber)); // Guarda o nome referente à imagem que foi sorteada
                }

                if(randomUrlList.get(i) != null){
                Picasso.with(getContext()).load(randomUrlList.get(i)).into(imgFotoPais); // Inserir na ImageView a imagem do respetivo país


                    txtPaisNome.setText(randomNomePaisList.get(i)); // Inserir na TextView o nome do respetivo país
```

And this is my **LOGCAT**
https://pastebin.com/REeBpAA5

And this is my **ADAPTER**

class CardStackAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

```
public CardStackAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) { return new CardStackFragment(); }

@Override
public int getCount() { return 5; }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

check list before entering data to it like :

```
if(!urlList.contains(url)){
    urlList.add(url); // Adiciona as imagens à lista
    nomePaisList.add(nomePais); // Adiciona os nomes à lista
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: I still get different images ahah, did not help

Comment: well, brother why are you making two different arraylist

Comment: better use one model class and make arraylist of that model it ll optimise and reduce the code

Comment: I could do that but I'm new to android and I don't know how to make it

Comment: have a look at my current answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    //model class => photos
    public class Photos{

       private String Imagem;
       private Stirng Nome;

       //now make constructors
       //and getters and setters

    }

    //now in your CardStackFragment.java change the data initialization method to this

    //init arraylist outside
    private ArrayList<Photos> photosArray;

    //now that's how you have to fetch data
    DatabaseReference countriesRef = mDatabase.child("paises");
    countriesRef .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapShot) {
          for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
             Photos mPhotos = ds.getValue(Photos.class);
             //check if the value already exist in the array
             if(!photosArray.contains(mPhotos)){
                 photosArray.add(mPhotos);
             }
          }
          //now let's render the data in the views
          //array of images to be used
          ArrayList<Photos> toBeUsed = new ArrayList();
          for (int i=0; i<=Constants.TOTAL_PAISES; i++){
                //now check if the image is already added to the array of to be used images
                if(!toBeUsed.contains(photosArray.get(randomNumber))){
                   toBeUsed.add(mPhotos);
                }
                Picasso.with(getContext()).load(toBeUsed.get(i).getImagem).into(imgFotoPais); 
                txtPaisNome.setText(toBeUsed.get(i).getNome);
          }
       }
       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
          //log the error
          Log.e("error in data fetching", databaseError.toString());
       }
    });



//now if you dont want to change your code
//then all you are required to check if the url has been added to randomUrlList
//so before adding the url and name do something like this

//your code

randomUrlList.add(urlList.get(randomNumber)); 
randomNomePaisList.add(nomePaisList.get(randomNumber));

//change it to

if(!randomUrlList.contains(urlList.get(randomNumber))){
   randomUrlList.add(urlList.get(randomNumber)); 
   randomNomePaisList.add(nomePaisList.get(randomNumber));
}


//thats it
//this time it's gonig to work for sure
```

Comment: Hm, I did the if that you mentioned last and I still get duplicate images ahaha

Comment: no last time i told you to do something else. this time your have to check your random arraylist before adding data to it. see the second part of the answer carefully

Comment: //your code

randomUrlList.add(urlList.get(randomNumber)); 
randomNomePaisList.add(nomePaisList.get(randomNumber));

//change it to

if(!randomUrlList.contains(urlList.get(randomNumber))){
   randomUrlList.add(urlList.get(randomNumber)); 
   randomNomePaisList.add(nomePaisList.get(randomNumber));
}

Comment: Yeah, I know, I changed it using the second part but it is still showing me repeated images ;)

Comment: It gives me this error:
  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Comment: please show me the line at which there is indexOutOfBound

Comment: I think it is when I apply the retrieved image to the imgView
`Picasso.with(getContext()).load(randomUrlList.get(i)).into(imgFotoPais);`

Comment: ok i got it
the reason it that when the image reapets it doesnt enter the value in the array list but your for loop goes till the end of the limit and causes indexOutOfBound

now the solution is very simple just before using the value make sure that the value exists 

use this code

if(randomUrlList.get(i) != null){ 
   Picasso.with(getContext()).load(randomUrlList.get(i)).into(imgFotoPais);
}

Comment: and do similarily for the image name

Comment: I did you said: ` if(randomUrlList.get(i) != null){....` and wrapped everything up inside that If but now it gives me the same error in the line 95 (which is that if statement)

Comment: please show me the log and show me lines from 90-100

Comment: ok brother i saw everything
now you can do one more thing

shift the rendering code to the this if block
if(!randomUrlList.contains(urlList.get(randomNumber))) {
    //here is the code about adding the random picture to array
   //an now you place your rendering code here : about placing image in imageview and setting name
}

Comment: So you're saying to wrap up everything from adding the random pic into the array to set the randomNomePaisList into the TextView?

Comment: ahaha sorry for saying this but, now doesn't crash but I still get repeated images

Comment: ok no problem. are you sure that there are no repeated images in your database ?

Comment: Yup, Im 100% sure!

Comment: ok show me you adapter which you are usinng to set the images into imageviews

Comment: Updated ;) check it, please

Comment: please show the whole code beacause importnt things like your array of images are missing

Comment: instead of => 
public int getCount() { return 5; }
use => 
public int getCount() { return yourArray.size(); }